# MAC-адреса систем из текущей подсети

Tags: shell, bash

Можно ли как-то вывести MAC-адреса всех сетевых интерфейсов для систем, которые имеют IP-адрес в подсетях исходной системы (то есть той, на которой запущен скрипт)? Используя `ssh` или `rsh`.

Как получить подсети, я нашел в интернете:

```
subnets=(` ifconfig -a | grep broadcast | gawk '{print $2}'`)
```

Думал воспользоваться командой ifconfig, но в сети пишут следующее:

> Результаты работы команды `ifconfig -а`
> будут разными в зависимости от того,
> кто ее вызывает: пользователь root или
> рядовой пользователь. Это касается
> обеих версий команды. В первом случае
> помимо IP-адресов и параметров
> отображаются также MAC-адреса.

Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт запускался от имени обычного пользователя, а не только от рута.
И как всё это соединить в единый скрипт? Мне нужно для `OS Solaris`. Будут ли отличия в работе, например, от выполнения на `Ubuntu`?

Comment: Как это перевести? Нужны mac-адреса данного хоста или (в случае локальной сети, напр ethernet) mac-адреса всех сетевых адаптеров в этой сети, или адреса всех адаптеров хостов, которые имеют интерфейс в этой сети?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ifconfig выдает сведения об интерфейсах **Вашего** компьютера (того, на котором эта команда вызывалась). ssh и rsh здесь ни при чем.

МАС адреса (части) компьютеров локального сегмента сети можно получить из вывода команды arp (по моему ключ -a, уточните в man), которая печатает данные из так называемой arp-таблицы (address resolution protocol table) . В ней хранится соответствие между IP и MAC адресами (в локальном сегменте).

Данные в нее заносятся по мере необходимости, поэтому она не содержит все MAC-и сегмента. Добавить в нее новую пару можно вызвав ping на интересующий IP. Однако будьте внимательны, старые пары автоматически удаляются, поэтому наивный алгоритм опроса может не показать все MAC-и в сегменте.

Для выполнения от root (если потребуется) всегда можно написать wrapper с -s атрибутом.